# Ajax send a post with multiple files

Tags: ajax

From Postman, I am able to send a POST request to the server successfully as following:

```
Key               Value
postinfo (file)   info.json
data     (file)   data.csv
label    (file)   label.csv
```

Now I'm implementing this in HTML and JavaScript.

```
<div id="fileupload">
  <form id="uploaddata" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Choose data file</label>
    <input type="file" accept="file/csv">
    <br>
    <label for="file">Choose initial label file</label>
    <input type="file">
    <br>
    <label for="file">Choose setting</label>
    <input type="file">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
  $('#uploaddata').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = new FormData($("#uploaddata")[0]);
    $.ajax({
      url: albackend,
      type:'POST',
      data: form,
      crossDomain: true,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success:function(data){
        console.log("success");
        console.log(data);
        $('#fileupload').hide();
        $('#videoselect').show();
      },
      error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });
```

Data is not posted successfully yet, likely due to lacking of keys (postinfo, data, label). How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your file inputs nave no name attributes, they need them to be the keys of the files in the request.

```
<div id="fileupload">
  <form id="uploaddata" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Choose data file</label>
    <input type="file" name="data" accept="file/csv">
    <br>
    <label for="file">Choose initial label file</label>
    <input type="file" name= "label">
    <br>
    <label for="file">Choose setting</label>
    <input type="file" name="postinfo">
    <br>
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```